# Gradient style is not available for ChartArea in Apex

Tags: apexcharts

Apex chart background color: we need apply the **gradient** style color for entier 'Chart Area '.
We could not find the **'gradient'** features in Apex Chart! Could you please help us to solve this problem?

**Gradient Style-DiagonalLeft**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUGNm.png)

**Gradient Style DiagonalRight**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAgK2.png)